# Testing Angular 1.5 Components $componentController is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm following the [documentation for testing Angular 1.5 components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#unit-testing-component-controllers).

I'm getting an error where $componentController is undefined. I'm sure it is something simple but I just can't see what is wrong here.

here is my test component.

```
class MyComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.counter = 0;
  }
  $onChanges() {}
  $onDestroy() {}
  addToCounter() {
    this.counter += 1;
  }
}

MyComponent.$inject = [];

angular.module( 'my.component', [] )
  .component( 'MyComponent', {
      controller: MyComponent,
      bindings: {},
      template: `
        <div>Hello World</div>
      `,
} );
```

Here is the test

```
describe( 'module: my.component', function() {

    var $componentController;

    beforeEach( module( 'my.component' ) );

    beforeEach( inject( function( _$componentController_ ) {
        $componentController = _$componentController_;
    } ) );

    it( 'should default counter to 0', function() {
        var bindings = {};
        console.log( '$componentController', $componentController );
        var ctrl = $componentController( 'MyComponent', null, bindings );
        expect( ctrl.counter )
            .toEqual( 0 );
    } );
} );
```

Here what Jasmine is outputting

```
LOG: '$componentController', undefined
...
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '$componentController( 'MyComponent', null, bindings )') in ...
```

Comment: Do you have the right version of Angular and Angular mocks installed for the test itself?

Comment: Yes Angular 1.5.9 for both

Comment: If nothing is wrong with the code I'll check the config again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to change your component name from "MyComponent" to "myComponent", a component name needs to start with a lower case letter.
I changed the test a bit by fetching the controller in the inject:

```
let controller;
beforeEach(() => {
   angular.mock.module( 'my.component' );
   inject(($componentController) => {
    controller = $componentController("myComponent");
   });
});
```

After doing so I ran these 3 tests:

```
describe("Just some test", () => {
  it("should fetch controller", () => {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });
  it("counter should be 0", () => {
    expect(controller.counter).toBe(0);
  });
  it("should increase counter value to 1", () => {
    controller.addToCounter();
    expect(controller.counter).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

And they all passed.

Comment: All I had to do was change "MyComponent" to "myComponent" I knew I was missing something simple, Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Try MyComponent istead of my.componenet